# Excel vlookup in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, vlookup

How can i make vlookup like in excel to pandas, i'm totally begginer in python. My first and second dataframe like this

```
data_01 = pd.DataFrame({'Tipe Car':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Branch':['UD', 'UA', 'UK', 'UA'], 'Area':['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D']})
data_02 = pd.DataFrame({'Tipe Car':['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], 'Branch':['UD', 'UA', 'UK', 'UA']})
```

and then expected output is

```
data_03 = pd.DataFrame({'Tipe Car':['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], 'Branch':['UD', 'UA', 'UK', 'UA'], 'Area':['1A', '1B', 'NaN', 'NaN']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Tipe Car':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Branch':['UD', 'UA', 'UK', 'UA'], 'Area':['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Tipe Car':['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], 'Branch':['UD', 'UA', 'UK', 'UA']})

df1.set_index('Tipe Car').join(df2.set_index('Tipe Car'), how='right', lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2')
>>>
         Branch_df1 Area Branch_df2
Tipe Car                           
A                UD   1A         UD
B                UA   1B         UA
E               NaN  NaN         UK
F               NaN  NaN         UA
```

Comment: i think what i expected is column 'tipe car' together with other column, so it's just like vlookup in excel. It means that second dataframe has a new column that fill with the result from vlookup.

Comment: Apply `.reset_index()` to the result if you want to convert the 'tipe car' index as a data column. If you don't want duplicated 'branch' columns in the result, use `df1[[''tipe car", "area"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data_04 = pd.merge(data_01,data_02, on='Tipe Car', how='right')
data_04_col=list(data_04.columns)
data_04=data_04[[data_04_col[0],data_04_col[3],data_04_col[2]]]
```